# Capture a specific INFO level data from JMeter Log Viewer and display in JMeter Listener or CSV or HTML Report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, logging, junit, jmeter, webdriver

I am executing a script which captures order search activity in Salesforce QA sandbox with **Chrome Webdriver** (latest ver.). The steps are written in Selenium JUnit code, the Selenium project is exported as JAR and the JAR is executed in JMeter 5.4.1, using **JUnit Request Sampler** (JUnit ver. 4.13.2). During test run, each step executed by chrome window is captured in the Log Viewer of JMeter (as INFO).

There is one specific variable declared [long ElapsedTime] in the selenium code which captures the Elapsed Time between Search ID entered and ID record found:

```
*log.info(threadName + "::  limsId value is: " + limsId);
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
**long timeElapsed = endTime - startTime;
log.info(threadName + "::  Execution time in milliseconds: " + timeElapsed);**
driver.close();*
```

and is as displayed in Log Viewer as below:

```
*2021-05-31 10:47:39,139 INFO s.QATest: Thread Group 1-1::  Waiting over.....
2021-05-31 10:47:39,184 INFO s.QATest: Thread Group 1-1::  limsId value is: ADM3064A2
**2021-05-31 10:47:39,185 INFO s.QATest: Thread Group 1-1::  Execution time in milliseconds: 20068***
```

This value is only captured in Logs and not in any Listener in JMeter. Unlike Webscript, I am not sure if Transaction controller for each flow can be added.

How can I get this value displayed exclusively either in a Listener/ or CSV file or JTL file, from where I can create a HTML Report which also shows this intermediate result.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   sample_variables=timeElapsed
   ```
2. Add the next line to your JUnit test:

   ```
   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables().put("timeElapsed", String.valueOf(timeElapsed));
   ```

This way next time when you [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) you will see an extra column called `timeElapsed` containing the value of your `timeElapsed` variable for each and every sample result.

More information: [Sample Variables property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)

You should be able to plot the value as the [custom chart of the HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs)

Comment: Thank you. This worked out and I am able to capture the variable in .jtl and also plot it against custom graph through Jmeter generated HTML report.